# How to check if annotation is present without complex reflection field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following classes :

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyClassA extends MyClassB{
    private String name;
    private String firstName;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class MyClassB {
   @MyCustomAnnotation
   private String age;
}

// MyCustomAnnotation class
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation{
       
}
```

Then I can easily retrieve the property value by using org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils for example.

```
MyClassA bean = new MyClassA("foo", "bar", 25);
String value = PropertyUtils.getProperty(bean, "age");
System.out.println(value);
```

My question is, Is there any efficient way (like when retrieving the value above) to check if **@MyCustomAnnotation** is present on a field or its getter, and no matter if the field is on the current class or the sub-class, without using complex reflection ?
I've done some research on org.springframework.util.Reflectionutils, org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils and org.springframework.bean.BeanWrapper but they seems to not have any solution on my problem.

Note : To avoid confusion, I know that it is possible using reflection. Question is like PropertyUtils/Beanwrapper for retrieving value, is there library to get the annotation. I just don't want to have org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils library to get the value and have some java reflection to get the annotation.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english, it's not my mother language

Comment: "_I've done some research on org.springframework.util.Reflectionutils, org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils and org.springframework.bean.BeanWrapper but they seems to not have any solution on my problem._" - that seems to be your answer. Even if you add a convenience method to your class, the solution will most likely be reflective in nature; ESPECIALLY if the library you are using for the annotations doesn't have such convenience method to begin with.

Comment: I am going to try find a solution for you.

Comment: This is tricky... the answer is DEPENDS. I believe that if the annotation has a retention policy of SOURCE, you won't be able to do what you are asking. You need to  provide the exact annotation class and let me investigate. If the policy is RUNTIME, then I will have an answer for you.

Comment: @hfontanez oh sorry, I forgot to add MyCustomAnnotation class. I've updated my question. To anwser to your question, the policy is Runtime

Comment: There's no way to find out at runtime if a field is annotated without using reflection. Why don't you like reflection, because you heard it's slow?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes something like that; but also to have a more readable code. It's like I can retrieve the value in one line of code using PropertyUtils and Beanwrapper, so I'm looking for a way to get the annotation (I guess that reflection behind these libraries)

Comment: @zozonenete give me a few minutes and I will code the solution for you.

Comment: @zozonenete Check my posted answer. I tried this with `Field` earlier at work and worked fine. I just wrote this in haste, so it may have an error or two here and there. I could not run it because Eclipse decided to start acting up and has been "building" forever and I have to run to the store. Try it and let me know if it works. I will check again when I come back.

Comment: It is (AFAIK) not possible to do this without using reflection.  And hfontanez's solution does use reflection. Whether it is *complex* reflection is a matter of opinion.  (I don't think it is.)

Comment: @StephenC I know it is possible using reflection. Question is like PropertyUtils for retrieving value, is there library. I just don't want to have PropertyUtils and Reflection both in my code

Comment: So your question needs to be **clear** about what >you< mean by "complex reflection".  (And saying different / seemingly contradictory things in the title, the body, and a "PS" section does not count as "clear" ... to me.)

Comment: Yep, I changed my question to avoid confusion

Comment: Well yea I see you tried ... but you didn't succeed.

Comment: It is also unclear what you mean by `PropertyUtils` and `Reflection`.  Which specific classes / libraries are you referring to there?

Comment: @zozonenete the code I provided worked. The sample code returns `true`, meaning that the `toString()` method is annotated as `Deprecated`.

Comment: @zozonenete I got it to work. It was kinda dumb on my part for not reading the Javadocs

Answer (score -1):

Your solution should look something like this:

**UPDATE**:

I created a utility class where you pass the target object, and the rest of the parameters from the previous example. The only differences are that

1. You have to set fields (and methods) accessible if they are not public.
2. If the declared field is not in the target's class, then you got to check the parent. Potentially, you might have to make this function recursive to go all the way up the hierarch tree, but for this simple example of one parent class, it works fine.
3. The parent class fields should not be private. They should be at least `protected` because private fields are not accessible by the child class.

With that, given the following classes with annotated field and with this custom annotation...

```
public class MyClassB {
    @MyCustomAnnotation
    protected String age;
}

public class MyClassA extends MyClassB {
    private String name;
    private String firstName;
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation{

}
```

```
public class AnnotationCheck {
    public static boolean isFieldAnnotationPresent(Object target, Class annotation, String name) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Field field = null;
        boolean isPresent = false;
        try {
            field =  target.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
            field.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
            Class parent = target.getClass().getSuperclass();
            if(parent == null) {
                throw nsfe;
            } else {
                field = parent.getDeclaredField(name);
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }
        }
        return field.isAnnotationPresent(annotation);
    }
}
```

If I run this test:

```
public class TestAnnotation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        MyClassA target = new MyClassA();
        System.out.println(AnnotationCheck.isFieldAnnotationPresent(target, MyCustomAnnotation.class, "age"));
        System.out.println(AnnotationCheck.isFieldAnnotationPresent(target, MyCustomAnnotation.class, "firstName"));
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: @StephenC I forgot to enclose it in quotes. It was meant as a sarcastic comment. I posted this earlier in the comments section "_Even if you add a convenience method to your class, the solution will most likely be reflective in nature; ESPECIALLY if the library you are using for the annotations doesn't have such convenience method to begin with._" I was 99.99% convinced a solution HAS to be reflective in nature.

Comment: It's not working when the method or field is in sub-class that inherited by AnnotationCheck. But with recursive function, it should working. I think that I have no choice and I will have to use some java reflection. Thanks for your anwser

Comment: I just did as a simple example. If you extract that method to a utility class and you pass the object's instance, it should work. I will try to modify my answer.

Comment: I take inspiration from your example, it shoud help me a lot

Comment: `getClass().getMethod` isn’t reflective? This is the opposite of a “non-reflective” solution.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Read my reply to Stephen C.